# python regex - no match in script, although it should

Tags: python, regex

I am programming a parser for an old dictionary and I'm trying to find a pattern like re.findall("{.*}", string) in a string.
A control print after the check proves, that only a few strings match, although all strings contain a pattern like {...}. 
Even copying the string and matching it interactively in the idle shell
gives a match, but inside the rest of the code, it simply does not.

Is it possible that this problem is caused by the actual python interpreter?
I cannot figure out any other problem...

thanks for your help

the code snippet looks like that:

```
        for aParse in chunklist:
            aSigle = aParse[1]
            aParse = aParse[0]
            print("to be parsed", aParse)

            aContext = Context()
            aContext._init_("")
            aContext.ID = contextID
            aContext.source = aSigle

            # here, aParse is the string containing {Abriss}
            # which is part of a lexicon entry
            metamatches = re.findall("\{.*\}", aParse)
            print("metamatches: ", metamatches)

            for meta in metamatches:

                aMeta = meta.replace("{", "").replace("}", "")
                aMeta = aMeta.split()

                for elem in aMeta:
                   ...
```

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of the text you are trying to match? This will make it easier to figure out the issue.

Comment: if you could post few example strings that you need to print, it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re = {0: "{.test1}",1: "{.test1}",2: "{.test1}",3: "{.test1}"}
for value in re.itervalues():
    if "{" in value:
        value = value.replace("{"," ")
        print value
```

or if you want to remove both "{}”

```
for value in re.itervalues():
    if "{" in value:
        value = value.strip('{}')
        print value
```

Comment: As I understand you want to replace all values that contains '{.' ?

Comment: So, in a really simplified scenario, a lexical entry looks like that: <headword> {meta, meaning} context [reference for context].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data=re.findall(r"\{([^\}]*)}",aParse,re.I|re.S)
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/Cj8y)

Answer (score 0):

So, in a really simplified scenario, a lexical entry looks like that:

> > "headword" {meta, meaning} context [reference for context].

So, I was chunking (split()) the entry at [...] with a regex. that works fine so far. then, after separating the headword, I tried to find the meta/meaning with a regex that finds all patterns of the form {...}. Since that regex didn't work, I replaced it with this function:

```
def findMeta(self, string, alist):
    opened = 0
    closed = 0
    for char in enumerate(string):
        if char[1] == "{":
            opened = char[0]

        elif char[1] == "}":
            closed = char[0]
            meta = string[opened:closed+1]
            alist.append(meta)
            string.replace(meta, "")
```

Now, its effectively much faster and the meaning component is correctly analysed. The remaining question is: in how far are the regex which I use to find other information (e.g. orthographic variants, introduced by "s.}") reliable? should they work or is it possible that the IDLE shell is simply not capable of parsing a 1000 line program correctly (and compiling all regex)? an example for a string whose meta should actually have been found is: " {stm.}  {der abbruch thut, den armen das gebührende vorenthält} [Renn.]"
the algorithm finds the first, saying this word is a noun, but the second, it's translation, is not recognized.
... This is medieval German, sorry for that! Thank you for all your help.